# set_tsk_need_resched() behavior inside linux scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have been looking at the linux scheduler and the basics of task scheduling. set_tsk_need_resched() allows for rescheduling of a task. So I had a question regarding scheduling.

What is the behavior when a set_tsk_need_resched(next) is called inside a scheduler?

Does this force the scheduler be called again just soon as the scheduler selects the next task and returns from _schedule()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set_need_resched function does nothing but setting a NEED_RESCHED flag in the task struct which tells the scheduler that this task has to be rescheduled. So this task will get rescheduled on the next instance of the scheduler call. This normally happens when the task does a context switch or returning from interrupt or syscall return (again context switch) etc. or a lazy call to might_sleep(). The need resched flag is commonly set from the timer tick handler and with some special cases.